# How do I modify setDate to getFullYear less 1 day?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am not finding a way to modify so the end date for warranty is 1 full year less a day. Here is code if someone can help or point me to the right post for the answer? Here is the function I have now.

```
function setStdWarrEndDate(date) {
            var stdDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', date);
            stdDate.setFullYear(stdDate.getFullYear() + 1);
            $('#StdWarrantyEndDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', stdDate ));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
stdDate.setFullYear(stdDate.getFullYear() + 1);
stdDate.setDate(stdDate.getDate() - 1);
```

Comment: yes, I just figured it out! Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: @minglis No problem! If this helped, you might want to accept it as the answer. Let me know if you need more help with this stuff though :)